# angular, can't find element in html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

For some reason I can't get the value of the list element in the html despite using `document.getElementByID` and it has the same id. It claims that the element is undefined. Here is the code:

**fileupload.component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {  
  var x = document.getElementById('lemons'); 
  if(x){
    console.log('it does exits')
    x.addEventListener('click', function(e:any){
      console.log(x.innerHTML);
    });
  }
}
```

**fileupload.component.html:**

```
<div class="row" id="filesDisplay">
<div class="col-md-4" id="files">
    <li *ngFor="let child of tree" id="lemons">
            {{child}}
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: You could consider using `template-variable` with [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren), bind `click` listner directly using `(click)="myEvent($event)"`

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: Your template is incorrect: _each_ `<li>` element (representing a separate element of `tree` list) has the same id - `'lemons'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not repeat same html id for all the li's. You need to add index to id to diffrentiate.

```
 <div class="row" id="filesDisplay">
  <div class="col-md-4" id="files">
   <li *ngFor="let child of tree" (click)="test(child)">
        {{child}}
   </li>
</div>
```

and in javascript you need to pull the id accordingly.

```
  ngOnInit() {  
   test(res) {
     // perform your logic here..
    } 
}
```

You no need to use jquery here where angular is providing all your need in DOM manipulation.

Comment: what would I do if i wanted the item that they clicked on

Comment: This worked perfectly, however I didn't put it in the ngOnInit. I put it on the outside instead.

Answer (score 3):

The *ngFor directive is processed after the OnInit hook, so if you want to get an element generated with the *ngFor you should use:

```
ngAfterViewInit() { }
```

Also you are duplicating the id, this means it only will select the first element.

[lifecycle-hooks angular's guide](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Edit: added angular guide

Comment: This worked to register clicks but only prints the first element.

Comment: Yes because you are using the same id for all the <li> elements. So when you are printing the <li> innerHTML it only has the first one.